# R change duplicates to missing value or delete them

Tags: r, duplicates

I have the following dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
dummydat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Visite,  ~Pet,
  1L,      1L, "dog",
  1L,      2L, "dog",
  1L,      4L, "cat",
  1L,      4L, "dog",
  1L,      5L, "cat",
  1L,      6L, "cat",
  2L,      1L, "cat",
  2L,      2L, "cat",
  2L,      3L, "dog",
  2L,      4L, "dog",
  2L,      4L, "cat",
  2L,      6L, "dog",
  2L,      7L, "dog",
  3L,      1L, "cat",
  3L,      2L, "cat",
  3L,      3L, "dog",
  3L,      4L, "dog",
  3L,      4L, "cat",
  3L,      5L, "dog",
  3L,      6L, "dog"
)
dummydat
```

I would like to change the duplicates to the lower number of the visite if e.g. at ID 1 visite 4 or the lower visit is missing, to the higher visite if e.g. at ID 2 visite 5 or the higher visit is missing, or delete one whole row including all other values of a person if there is a duplicate but no adjacent visit is missing.

In this example at ID 1L the lower number is missing so Visite = 4L and Pet = cat should switch to Visite = 3L and Pet = cat.
At ID 2L the higher number is missing so Visite = 4L and Pet = cat should switch to Visite = 5L and Pet = cat.
At ID 3L no number is missing so one of the Visites = 4L should be deleted at random.

Thank you.
Best
Christina

Comment: One question about duplicates: if the `Visite` consists of `1,2,3,4,5,6,6`, then should this case be treated as "lack of `7`" or "duplicates of `6`"? I guess it should be clarified in advance such that others can contribute their answers in a correct way...

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help

```
library(dplyr)
dummydat %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Pet = replace(Pet, duplicated(Visite), NA),
   Visite = case_when(duplicated(Visite, fromLast = TRUE) ~
          lag(Visite) + 1L, TRUE ~ Visite)) %>% 
   filter(!duplicated(Visite))  %>% 
   filter(!is.na(Pet))
```

---

It could be also done by creating a sequence column, by 'ID', `filter` out the `duplicated` 'Visite' rows and then change the 'Visite' to 'row_number()`

```
dummydat %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(Visite)) %>%
    select(ID, Visite = rn, Pet)
```

Comment: Thank you. Deleting works great. But I need that ID1L and ID2L should change to the missing value Visite 3 (ID1) and Visit 5 (ID2):          
''' dummydat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Visite,  ~Pet,
  1L,      1L, "dog",
  1L,      2L, "dog",
  1L,      3L, "cat",
  1L,      4L, "dog",
  1L,      5L, "cat",
  1L,      6L, "cat",
  2L,      1L, "cat",
  2L,      2L, "cat",
  2L,      3L, "dog",
  2L,      4L, "dog",
  2L,      5L, "cat",
  2L,      6L, "dog",
  2L,      7L, "dog",
)
'''

Comment: Changing the first missing value works also fine. So only changing the following missing value like in ID2 still doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristinaSobotzki  Can you post the expected output

Answer (score 0):

It works! Thank you!

```
dummydat2<- dummydat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Visite = case_when(duplicated(Visite, fromLast = TRUE) ~
                              lag(Visite) + 1L, TRUE ~ Visite))
dummydat2

dummydat3<- dummydat2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Visite = case_when(duplicated(Visite, fromLast = FALSE) ~
                              lag(Visite) + 1L, TRUE ~ Visite))
dummydat3

dummydat4<- dummydat3 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% filter(!duplicated(Visite))  %>% 
           filter(!is.na(Pet))
dummydat4
```

Answer (score 0):

It suddenly doesn't work anymore!! I don't get it!

The result is:

```
# A tibble: 17 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID Visite Pet  
   <int>  <int> <chr>
 1     1     NA dog  
 2     1      2 dog  
 3     1      3 cat  
 4     1      5 dog  
 5     1      6 cat  
 6     2      7 cat  
 7     2      8 cat  
 8     2      3 dog  
 9     2      4 dog  
10     2      5 cat  
11     2      6 dog  
12     3      1 cat  
13     3      2 cat  
14     3      3 dog  
15     3      4 dog  
16     3      5 cat  
17     3      6 dog
```

The values get completely confused!